# Creating rows of content using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently running into a complication with a relatively involved ConstraintLayout-based implementation of a design.

[image]

The design is a row of items as seen above. These rows are static, and are shown/hidden depending on certain data-related conditions.

The issue I am running into is that I haven't found a reliable way to properly contain each row between the dividers/barriers I have in my layout.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, my constraint layout doesn't respect the barriers/dividers as expected. I've included the XML for this layout below.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FF354052"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/statusTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textGuideline"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="4:20 PM" />

                <com.weedmaps.driver.android.view.StatusTextView
                    android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="27dp"
                    android:paddingStart="27dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:background="@color/accepted_blue" />

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/headerDividerTopBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="top"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="headerDivider" />

                <!-- / end delivery status section -->

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/deliveryStatusSectionBottomBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="statusTextView, timeTextView, timeIcon" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/headerDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#FFE6EAEE"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/deliveryStatusSectionBottomBarrier"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/destinationInfoSectionTopBarrier" />

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/destinationInfoSectionTopBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="top"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="directionsIcon, addressTextContainer, locationIcon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/locationIcon"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_pin"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerDivider"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/customerInfoSectionTopBarrier" />

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/locationIconBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="end"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="locationIcon" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/addressTextContainer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerDivider"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/directionsIconBarrier"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textGuideline"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/customerInfoSectionTopBarrier">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/addressTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FF354052"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="423 Clyde Ford Apt. 25" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cityStateZipTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FF354052"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        tools:text="Irvine, CA 92602" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/directionsIconBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="start"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="directionsIcon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/directionsIcon"
                    android:layout_width="47dp"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerDivider"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/customerInfoSectionTopBarrier" />

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/destinationInfoSectionBottomBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="directionsIcon, addressTextContainer, locationIcon" />

                <!-- / end destination info section -->

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/destinationDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#FFE6EAEE"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/destinationInfoSectionBottomBarrier" />

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/customerInfoSectionTopBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="top"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="customerNotesLayout, smsIcon, phoneIcon, customerInfoLayout, personIcon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/personIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/customerInfoLayout" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/customerInfoLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/customerNotesLayout"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/phoneIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textGuideline"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/destinationDivider">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#FF354052"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="423 Clyde Ford Apt. 25ssdfsdasvewwevsrdggreve vevevrsv gaervavrvsevsevve0" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/viewDocumentsTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/delivery_detail_view_documents"
                        android:textColor="#FF354052"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/personIcon"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/phoneIcon"
                    android:layout_width="47dp"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_call"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/customerNotesLayout"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/smsIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/customerInfoLayout"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/destinationInfoSectionBottomBarrier"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/smsIcon"
                    android:layout_width="47dp"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chat"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/customerNotesLayout"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/phoneIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/destinationInfoSectionBottomBarrier"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/customerInfoAndIconBarrierBottom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="personIcon, customerInfoLayout, phoneIcon, smsIcon" />

                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/customerNotesLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/customerInfoAndIconBarrierBottom"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/customer_notes_gray"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:paddingStart="32dp"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/customer_note_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/customer_notes_title"
                            android:textColor="@color/darker_gray"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/customerNote"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.25"
                            android:textColor="@color/darker_gray"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            tools:text="iojsdfij siodfjosid fisdfj oidfj osidj fos fghfg hfhfg hgf hfgh fgh fgh fh fgh fghfgh fg fghf gh fgh f gf fgh f fgh gh fg fhfgh fhf hfghfghgfhfghfg hfgfisddjf " />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                    android:id="@+id/customerInfoSectionBottomBarrier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="customerNotesLayout, smsIcon, phoneIcon, customerInfoLayout, personIcon" />

                <!-- / end customer info section -->

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/customerDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#FFE6EAEE"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/customerInfoSectionBottomBarrier" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have a feeling that I am misusing something about constraint layout here, but I am not 100% sure of what that may be.

Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To be honest, I don't think `ConstraintLayout` is the best tool for this job. This looks like something that would be much easier with a `LinearLayout` as the root element. Yes, that will require you to add a few nested views, but that is a small price to pay for a more-easily maintainable app.

Comment: @BenP. Agreed on that, the original layout was already somewhat working with `ConstraintLayout`, and I am trying to reuse what's there already.

I even tried a `LinearLayout` at the root with several `ConstraintLayout` includes for each row. The problem is that this introduces a major performance issue due to all the `ConstraintLayout` measuring being done.

Comment: Really? Is this in a RecyclerView or ListView or something? One LinearLayout + four ConstraintLayouts + ~20 child views really shouldn't have any performance problems as compared to a single ConstraintLayout + 20 children. Have you actually measured and seen that a LinearLayout is too slow? Or are you just worried about performance in the abstract?

Comment: @BenP. The big performance issue is that we're putting this layout in a `CoordinatorLayout` with `BottomSheetBehavior` that is overlaid on top of a `MapFragment`. Without the `MapFragment` there, I would imagine my idea of several includes would work just fine.

I should also mention that yes, I have measured the performance in real-time, and it causes a lot of skipped frames on the UI thread. It's likely we have other performance issues that make this worse for us, but that's where we're at.

Comment: So you've actually built it with LinearLayout and have proof that it doesn't work?

Comment: @BenP. Yes, sorry I didn't include my answer to that question in my previous comment. I have edited it to include that information.

Comment: Fair enough. Looks like you've got a lot of work on your hands, then :)

Comment: I hope the below mentioned answer by me solves your problem and if it doesn't then please jot down a comment regarding what more you want to achieve.  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made the above layout keeping in mind almost all the use cases of what you want to achieve but still if anything else needs to be covered within it; please ask further and go through the code to understand it thoroughly.

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_time_icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF354052"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_time_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_time_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_status"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_time_icon"
        tools:text="4:20 PM" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="27dp"
        android:paddingEnd="27dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="ACCEPTED"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_time_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_time_icon" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_divider_line_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFE6EAEE"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_time_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_location_icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_divider_line_one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_below_complete_address" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_complete_address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_location_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_divider_line_one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier_below_complete_address"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_directions_icon">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF354052"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="423 Clyde Ford Apt. 25 Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum" />

        <!--
        Also, try:
        tools:text="423 Clyde Ford Apt. 25"
        In the TextView just above (i.e. with
        the id="@+id/tv_address").

        Works fine (for me) as per the use case.  -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_city_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF354052"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="Irvine, CA 92602" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--
    Barrier to place the views appropriately
    in case of increase or decrease in the
    address text i.e. the text placed within
    the TextView with the id="@+id/tv_address".  -->

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_below_complete_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="ll_complete_address" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_directions_icon"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_divider_line_one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier_below_complete_address" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_divider_line_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFE6EAEE"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_below_complete_address"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_person_icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_divider_line_two" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FF354052"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        tools:text="423 Clyde Ford Apt. 25 Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_person_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_person_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_call_icon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_view_documents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="View Documents"
        android:textColor="#FF354052"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_message_icon"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_call_icon"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_message_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_message_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_customer_notes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="32dp"
        android:paddingEnd="32dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_message_icon">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_customer_notes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            tools:text="CUSTOMER NOTES"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_customer_notes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.25"
            tools:text="Please don't knock on the door. I have a dog. Just call when you're here. Thank you. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum."
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_divider_line_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#FFE6EAEE"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_customer_notes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <!--
    To manage the visibility of each row,
    refer the grouping logic as applied
    below for each row (including its
    separator/divider line; which is just
    below it).

    Try changing the 'visibility' of each
    group to "gone".  -->

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group_row_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_time_icon, tv_time, tv_status, v_divider_line_one" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group_row_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_location_icon, ll_complete_address, iv_directions_icon, v_divider_line_two" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group_row_three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_person_icon, tv_name, tv_view_documents, iv_call_icon, iv_message_icon, v_divider_line_three, ll_customer_notes" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshots (for the above code):**

*1] With more address text.*

[image]

*2] With less address text.*

[image]

I hope, this helps you and also enhances your understanding about certain things in `ConstraintLayout` like `Barrier`, `Group` etc.